# C++: Pointer pointing to multi-dimensional array: "incompatible to the parameter of type"

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am programming a game where I have a class called `Wizard` and another class called `Judge`.

In `main`, I `Wizard wizard[7][7];`. And now I am suppose to hand the 7*7 Wizard array to a static method in Judge

`static void Initialize(short teamMax, short wizardMax, Wizard*** wizard) {/*stuff...*/};`

Well, the stuff (which the compiler did not find any error in) goes like:

```
    for (int i = 1, n = 1; i <= teamMax; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= wizardMax; j++)
        {
            Judge::Livings[n] = wizard[i][j]; 
            n++; 
        }
    }
```

Now this part worked out fine, but when I was calling this function in `main`

```
Wizard wizard[7][7]; 
Judge::Initialize(teamMax, wizardMax, &wizard);
```

It says "incompatible to the parameter of type".

I did some research but I just can't figure out what went wrong... so please help and thanks alot.

Comment: Arrays are *NOT* pointers! I'd use a multidimensional `std::array` instead of a multidimensional built-in in any case, especially when passing it into a function. Also, typically, for loops are [0, N) instead of (0, N]. That makes a big difference with the array access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify your array arg in Initialize as

```
static void Initialize(short teamMax, short wizardMax, Wizard wizard[][7])
```

read the following link:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/